how to sync my codes between tradingview and vscode
I have some indicator codes in trading view and need to archive them in my pc time to time, it's need much time to copy and paste them manually, is there any extension or something like that to do this process automatically?
I have done this manually one by one for every indicator before.

There are no extensions for VS Code or any other IDE as of now. You should keep doing it manually or develop your own tool.
